# imagecodecs python library won't install

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip

I was trying to install the python scikit-image library using pip on a Jetson Xavier, and I got an extremely long error message indicating that it had failed to build the wheel for the "imagecodecs" library. I tried to install imagecodecs by itself and received a similar error message.

After some looking around, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777875/problem-installing-scikit-image-probably-due-to-blosc) question, and the error is identical to my own. However, the solution of updating pip did not fix the issue.

**Error Message:**

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-iu5szk39/imagecodecs/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-iu5szk39/imagecodecs/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-5h3fo15u
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-iu5szk39/imagecodecs/

...

  At top level:
  imagecodecs/_tiff.c:10261:47: warning: ‘__pyx_f_11imagecodecs_5_tiff_memtif_new’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   static __pyx_t_11imagecodecs_5_tiff_memtif_t *__pyx_f_11imagecodecs_5_tiff_memtif_new(toff_t __pyx_v_size, toff_t __pyx_v_inc) {
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for imagecodecs
  Running setup.py clean for imagecodecs
Failed to build imagecodecs
Installing collected packages: imagecodecs
    Running setup.py install for imagecodecs ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-iu5szk39/imagecodecs/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-iu5szk39/imagecodecs/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ttclns6b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6/imagecodecs
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-iu5szk39/imagecodecs/

...
At top level:
    imagecodecs/_tiff.c:10261:47: warning: ‘__pyx_f_11imagecodecs_5_tiff_memtif_new’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static __pyx_t_11imagecodecs_5_tiff_memtif_t *__pyx_f_11imagecodecs_5_tiff_memtif_new(toff_t __pyx_v_size, toff_t __pyx_v_inc) {
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-iu5szk39/imagecodecs/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-iu5szk39/imagecodecs/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ttclns6b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6/imagecodecs Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading pip using this command.

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

pip should now be on the latest version.

```
 $ pip3 --version
pip 20.1.1 from ...
```

Then install using pip3

```
pip3 install scikit-image
```

Comment: I’m using the latest version of pip, but I tried to upgrade just in case, latest version already installed and still no luck installing imagecodecs.